# what is optimal way to parse following kafka JSON message to pyspark dataframe?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark structured streaming to read kafka topic and want to convert following complex JSON (kafka-msgs) in to dataframe having "NAME,ADDRESS,DESCRIPTION,CODE,DEPARTMENT,INFA_OP_TYPE,DTL__CAPXTIMESTAMP" columns.

```
{ 
  "meta_data": [{"name":{"string":"INFA_SEQUENCE"},"value": 
{"string":"2,PWX_GENERIC"},"type":null},
          {"name":{"string":"INFA_TABLE_NAME"},"value":{"string":"customers"},"type":null},
          {"name":{"string":"INFA_OP_TYPE"},"value":{"string":"INSERT_EVENT"},"type":null},
          {"name":{"string":"DTL__CAPXRESTART1"},"value":{"string":"B+IABwAfA"},"type":null},
          {"name":{"string":"DTL__CAPXRESTART2"},"value":{"string":"AAABpMwgRDk="},"type":null},
          {"name":{"string":"DTL__CAPXUOW"},"value":{"string":"AAMKPgAAqaIABg=="},"type":null},
          {"name":{"string":"DTL__CAPXUSER"},"value":null,"type":null},
          {"name":{"string":"DTL__CAPXTIMESTAMP"},"value":{"string":"201807310934257270000000"},"type":null},
          {"name":{"string":"DTL__CAPXACTION"},"value":{"string":"I"},"type":null}],
"columns":{"array":[{"name":{"string":"NAME"},"value":{"string":"ABCD"},"isPresent":{"boolean":true}},
                  {"name":{"string":"ADDRESS"},"value":{"string":"123,Bark street"},"isPresent":{"boolean":true}},
                  {"name":{"string":"DESCRIPTION"},"value":{"string":"Canadian"},"isPresent":{"boolean":true}},
                  {"name":{"string":"CODE"},"value":{"string":"3_1"},"isPresent":{"boolean":true}},
                  {"name":{"string":"DEPARTMENT"},"value":{"string":"HR"},"isPresent":{"boolean":true}}
                 ]     }
}
```

I'm able to extract two json object "meta_data" and "columns" but I'm unable to explode "columns.array"

```
newJsonObj = events.select(get_json_object(events.value,'$.meta_data').alias('meta_data'),get_json_object(events.value,'$.columns.array').alias('columns'))
```

And I don't know how to extract values from two json object and create dataframe having columns from both json object.

-- Schema of events dataframe --

```
root
|-- columns: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- array: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- isPresent: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- boolean: boolean (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- string: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- string: string (nullable = true)
|-- meta_data: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- string: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- string: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you show the schema of the events DF?

Comment: I edit the post and include schema of events.. basically it is the schema of mentioned complex JSON.   Thanks.

Comment: If `meta_data` is an array, I think youll want to use `explode` function